# Create nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like the 3 columns here:

```
Automated test case name    TC Type     Module Name
        name 1              Pre-Req      Module 1
        name 2              Pre-Req      Module 1
        name 3              Pre-Req      Module 1
        name 4              Pre-Req      Module 1
        name 5              Actual       Module 1
        name 6              Actual       Module 1
        name 7              Pre-Req      Module 2
        name 8              Actual       Module 2
```

What I have done is: if `"Actual"` word is found in the column `'TC Type'`, then add all the previous `"Pre-Req"` with all `"Actual"`; if I find `"Actual"` consecutively, I need to take all the `"Pre-Req"` before the two `"Actual"`.

The code:

```
new_list = []
df = data_TC1
Dict_TestCase_Mapping = {}
is_ActualFound = False
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if "Actual" == df['TC Type'][i]:
        Dict_TestCase_Mapping[df['Automated test case name'][i]] = [i, new_list]
        is_ActualFound = True
    elif is_ActualFound and df['TC Type'][i] != "Actual":
        new_list = []
        new_list.append(df['Automated test case name'][i])
        is_ActualFound = False
    else:
        new_list.append(df['Automated test case name'][i])
```

Current output:

```
{
    name 5: [4, [name 1,
        name 2,
        name 3,
        name 4
    ]],
    name 6: [5, [name 1,
        name 2,
        name 3,
        name 4
    ]],
    name 8: [7, [name 7]]
}
```

What I want is `Module Name` as the key of the above dictonary.

Expected output:

```
{
    Module 1: {
        name 5: [4, [name 1,
            name 2,
            name 3,
            name 4
        ]],
        name 6: [5, [name 1,
            name 2,
            name 3,
            name 4
        ]]
    },
    Module 2: {
        name 8: [7, [name 7]]
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this output? Any help received will be appreciated.

Comment: what is `Dict_TestCase_Mapping` ?

Comment: it is a Dictonary which was defined as empty initially.

Comment: @ Paul Nicolas hunter Please see the edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please provide better description with role of modules included?

What I can propose is:

```
new_list = []
df = data_TC1
Dict_TestCase_Mapping = {}
is_ActualFound = False
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if "Actual" == df['TC Type'][i]:
        module_name = df['Module name'][i]
        if module_name not in Dict_TestCase_Mapping:
            Dict_TestCase_Mapping[module_name] = {}
        Dict_TestCase_Mapping[module_name][df['Automated test case name'][i]] = [i, new_list]
        is_ActualFound = True
    elif is_ActualFound and df['TC Type'][i] != "Actual":
        new_list = []
        new_list.append(df['Automated test case name'][i])
        is_ActualFound = False
    else:
        new_list.append(df['Automated test case name'][i])
```

Note that it's definitely not a pythonic/pandas way.

Comment: ,Basically ,Module name should be the key  initially to start with all those key-Value pair should  be added to Module name key if it exists in same module

Comment: @CyleySimon, then the code should work just fine. However, I encourage to write it in Python/pandas way. In any case happy to help :)

Comment: This have worked thank you for the help. I will let you know If i require any further help .. thanks once again , I am new to python

Comment: I am getting the answer using ablove logic , but earlier I have applied logic for The column "TC Type ", where if I find the word actual , then add all the previous  "Pre-Req" with all "Actual"; if I find "Actual" consecutively, I need to take all the "Pre-Req" before the two "Actual", but I just want to check theses for particular modules .If In module 2(from Module name column),If first one is actual  and there is no previous  'Pre-req 'then the dictonary of that actual test case should remain empty. How do we do this?